# Text analytics process workflow

Tags: frameworks, search-engine, text-analysis

I am doing a project to design a text analytics workflow (framework) prototype. The purpose of this workflow is to improve hotel search ranking results. We can use data from various sources(reviews,  third-party crawled data,etc).

Doe anyone know any tech blog/books which have these kinds of examples? I have been googling for a while but could not find a typical example.

Thanks!